# dropdbown button dinamically added: how to trigger delegated event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with bootstrap 3.3.7.
On a page I have a table: in one column of the table there is a dropdown button. I am adding rows to that table dinamically and each of those rows brings a dropdown button. Those added buttons don't open (they rely on some js to open and are not there on DOM ready).
How can I add event delegation to those dropdown? I have no problem with the inside link. They will work even if added. But I cannot access them since I cannot open the dropdown.

Table code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-md-1">
        <i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" title="Questo form &egrave; pubblico"></i>
    </td>
    <td class="col-md-9">ospiti del B&B</td>
    <td class="col-md-2">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gestisci form <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" data-value="TorTjWzAe4iZPV0B" class="compila"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> Compila</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-value="7" class="autore"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span> Contatta autore</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-value="7" data-role="formdacompilare" class="bug"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Segnala un problema</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-value="7" class="link-get"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link" aria-hidden="true"></span> Link Form</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS that will add the row:

```
$('#add_form_pubblico').click(function(){
        bootbox.prompt({
            title: "Inserisci l'url del form pubblico che vuoi aggiungere", 
            centerVertical: true,
            callback: function(result){ 
                if(result){
                    var public_token = result.replace("form.php?token=", ""); 
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "put_public_token.php",
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {public_token: public_token}
                    }).done(function(data){
                        bootbox.alert({
                            message: data.messaggio,
                            backdrop: true
                        }); 
                        $("#da_compilare tbody").append(data.html);
                    });                    
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#add_form_pubblico').on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', function(e) {
    var el = $(e.currentTarget); // Link that was clicked.
    // ....
});
```

This is if I assume that '#add_form_pubblico' is id of a parent element that is present on page load (it is not in your HTML). Substitute it with whatever element you have, or even $('document')